# Use Futurebuilder to create a DropdownFormField Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and have a array in firestore. It's structure is:
[image]

Now i want to fetch that array, and use that array to build a dropdownFormfield.
My fetch Function is following:

```
fetchSchoolList() async {
List<dynamic> data = [];
Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> result = schoolList.doc('List').get();

return result;
}
```

and my FutureBuilder is:

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(
                  future: fetchSchoolList(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.active) {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("Something went wrong");
                    }
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      print(snapshot);
                    }
                    return Text('Loading List');
                    }),
```

But with this i'm even unable to get that array to print. I am getting error:
**type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>?'**

Please help, i'm stuck here for days.#

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you could do:

First of all change `fetchSchoolList() async {...}` to something like this:

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot<List<String>?>>() async {
  Future<DocumentSnapshot<List<String>?>> result =schoolList.doc('List').get();
  
  return result;
}
```

Object isn't exactly a type, also flutter doesn't really know how to store information in with the type `<Object>`. Also you don't reference the `data` variable anywhere so it has been omitted.

Next change your `FutureBuilder` to something like this:

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<List<String>?>>(
              future: fetchSchoolList(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                    ConnectionState.active) {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("Something went wrong");
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  print(snapshot);
                }
                return Text('Loading List');
                }),
```

This will specify what is being returned by the future (Basically the `FutureBuilder`'s type) and because of that, you do not need to specify the snapshot type.

Comment: Also I'm not 100% sure if it's List<String?> or List<String>?, but i believe the one I specified in the code sample should be the right one.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer or let me know if any problems persist.